# Rails partial works when invoked at the end of a page, not in the middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial

I have the following code section:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_computer_path(@computer) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', computers_path %>

<div>
  <h2>New config</h2>
  <%= render "kernel_configs/computerkernelconfig", :locals => { :computer => @computer } %>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Submitted Configs</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Contributor</th>
      <th>Features</th>
      <th>Config file</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    <%= render @computer.kernel_configs %>

  </table>
</div>
```

which complains there is no route:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit",
>   :controller=>"kernel_configs", :id=>#}):
>   app/views/kernel_configs/_kernel_config.html.erb:13:in
>   `_app_views_kernel_configs__kernel_config_html_erb___3252059691242213705_26424640'
>   app/views/computers/show.html.erb:34:in`
>   _app_views_computers_show_html_erb___4341746115390966607_23819760'
>   app/controllers/computers_controller.rb:18:in `show'

If I move the first render after the second, then the page renders fine without errors.  So I'm pretty sure there is a route, in fact one of these probably:

```
 edit_kernel_config GET    /kernel_configs/:id/edit(.:format)   kernel_configs#edit
 edit_computer_kernel_config GET    /computers/:computer_id/kernel_configs/:id/edit(.:format)    kernel_configs#edit
```

For reference, the partial is here:

```
<%= form_for( [@computer,@computer.kernel_configs.build], :multipart => true ) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :contributed_by %>
    <%= form.text_field :contributed_by %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :features %><br />
    <%= form.text_area :features %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Upload File" %><br />
    <%= form.file_field :kernelconfig %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

_kernel_congif partial:

```
<tr>

  <td><%= kernel_config.rating %></td>

  <td><%= kernel_config.title %></td>

  <td><%= kernel_config.contributed_by %></td>

  <td><%= kernel_config.features %></td>

  <td><%= truncate kernel_config.kernelconfig %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kernel_config_path(kernel_config) %></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that since you have the form before the list, you are calling `@computer.kernel_configs.build` which adds a new empty record to `@computer.kernel_configs`.

Your partial is probably crashing because you are trying to display this new empty record.

This is why when you move the form partial below the collection partial, it works just fine.

EDIT:

As expected, you have are trying to create a link to an empty object.

The error is happening at the following line:

```
# _kernel_config.html.erb
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kernel_config_path(kernel_config) %></td>
```

The `edit_kernel_config_path` cannot find a path to an empty `kernel_config`.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at.  However, wouldn't the form have the same problem displaying this empty record regardless of whether it was before or after the collection?

Comment: The form is not displaying the empty record, it is not accessing any attributes. It looks like in your partial you are creating a link somewhere, and the error is coming from there. Could you post your _kernel_config.html.erb file?

Comment: I added the partial at the end.  It's only purpose is to display the contents of <%= @computer.kernel_confif %>

Comment: Just to be clear, it is this render which is failing if it is First:  <%= render "kernel_configs/computerkernelconfig",

Comment: Yeah so you are indeed creating a link in your partial, and it is failing because you are trying to create a link to an edit action of a `kernel_config` that has no `id`.

Comment: I understand, but don't see how moving it causes it to break.

Comment: I see now.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Added "unless ! nil?" to the link_to.